# What is <built-in method clear of dict object at 0x0012E540> saying?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm reading about object-oriented programming to try and understand it better when I came across:

```
print a_dict.clear
<built-in method clear of dict object at 0x0012E540>
```

And I'm trying to understand the results of the print statement. I get that Python is telling me that clear is a method belonging to the dict object, what does 0x0012E540 mean? Is that the "location" or where I can find the code for the clear method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use print , the statement "tries" first to cast the object to a string. If no __str__ method has been defined for this object the __repr__ function is used instead. The basic version of this function displays the type of the object alongside its in-memory address.

Source: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr